# Ios7 safari control top and bottom navigation/tool bars

Tags: mobile-safari, ios7

I'd like to know if in **IOS7 safari** there is a method for controlling the position of the address bar and the toolbar. I would basically like them to hide them as soon as the page loads in safari without the user having to scrolldown the page to invoke the hide?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no known method of doing this.

Source: http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review

Comment: The only workaround at this time is to tell users to download and use Google Chrome as their browser instead of Safari. Google Chrome support full screen browsing.